# How to get google sheets to reorder based on ranking

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I have created a Google Sheet that has a "days since" rank based on differences from todays date to date of the last "incident".

These days update automatically, but what I want is to have a ranking system where the Google Sheet reorders if the date of someone's last incident changes.

Is this possible? I have attached the link below, but it is a very simple formula as of now.

Row D: `=today()-C3`

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12SUfrB7XuqGlfxjvaePHJTGaZz_FhjiWhLxjPMAM2jI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to automatically sort the data with the column "C" when users edited the cells "C3:C8".

  - The table of the data is the cells "A3:D8".
- From your tag of `google-apps-script`, I thought that your direction includes to use Google Apps Script.

In this case, I would like to propose to use OnEdit simple trigger for achieving your goal. The sample script is as follows

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the container-bound script of the Spreadsheet and save it.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Sheet1" && range.getRow() >= 3 && range.getRow() <= 8 && range.getColumn() == 3) {
    sheet.getRange("A3:D8").sort({column: 3, ascending: true});
  }
}
```

- When you edit the cells "C3:C8", the script is automatically run by the OnEdit simple trigger, and the data is sorted with the column "C".

#### Result:

When your shared Spreadsheet is used with above sample script, the following result can be obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- When you want to sort with the column "D", please modify above script as follows.

  - From

    ```
      sheet.getRange("A3:D8").sort({column: 3, ascending: true});
    ```
  - To

    ```
      sheet.getRange("A3:D8").sort({column: 4, ascending: false});
    ```

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [sort(sortSpecObj)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Google Apps Script you may duplicate this table (in sheet2 for example) and have it's content duplicated there within sort() function.
Lets say you put
`=sort(Sheet1!A3:D8,4,0)` in `A3` cell of new `Sheet2`

I know it's not exactly the goal...